# django template language - if statement issues

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

i am kind of new to django and i ran into a problem i couldnt find a solution to. In a template i render data from a custom context processor. There i use a for loop over all the queried items and a if statement, that checks that the data belongs to the person that is currently logged in:

```
{% for item in all_soli_accs %}
    {% if item.owner == request.user.get_username %}
        <a href="{% url 'url-soli-acc' item.soli_acc %} ">
            {{ item.soli_acc }}   
        </a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Weirdly, the if statement doesnt return "true", when it is supposed to. The rendering doesnt output anything. In order to debug it, i tried to render `{{item.owner}}` and `{{request.user.get_username}}` and check if there are errors. But rendered as a variable, they return the same output, which lets me assume that it is all fine. I am confused. Does anyone has a solution to that? Do you need further information?

best regards

Comment: Try `{% if item.owner == request.user %}`. When rendering a User the `__str__` method returns the result of `get_username()` so while you get the same output onne is a User and the other is a strinng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
request.user.username
```

Instead of

```
request.user.get_username
```